# Add marker to image - trouble converting back from relative to absolute coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add markers to an image. I don't think it's useful nor practical converting it to an image map.

When a user clicks on the image, it should place a marker. I can retrieve the relative coordinates but then I cannot place the marker because I can't get the absolute coordinates I think.

I'm trying to do something very similar to this plugin: http://waynegm.github.io/imgNotes/examples/basic_interactive.html (click edit on the bottom and then on the image)

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/m3HXe/

```
$('#AddSensors_img').click(function (e) {
    var rpos = [];
    rpos.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rpos.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

    if (rpos) {

        var el = $(document.createElement('span')).addClass("marker black").html("1");
        var pos = [];

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        pos.x = Math.round($(window).scrollLeft()-rpos.x);
        pos.y = Math.round($(window).scrollTop() -rpos.y);
         console.log(pos);

        if (pos) {
            $(el).css({
                left: (pos.x),
                top: (pos.y),
                position: "absolute"
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Also tried this:

```
$('#AddSensors_img').click(function (e) {
    var rpos = [];
    rpos.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    rpos.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    var marker = $('span').addClass('marker black').html("1");
    marker.css({
        left: rpos.x,
        top: rpos.y
    })
    marker.appendTo(this);

});
```

Comment: I've done something very similar. If you can't get the coordinates relative to the document. Just get the starting point of the parent container of your image. Then, If you have image's height and width, you can place your marker wherever you want over it, based on parent container offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a wrapper that will have `postion: relative` and you image will have `position: absolute` (the same as markers) then you can use offset to get relative value and use to place a marker.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <img src="some_image.png"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper { position: relative; }
#wrapper img, #wrapper .marker { position: absolute; }
#wrapper .marker { z-index: 100; }
#wrapper img { top: 0; left: 0; }
```

javascript:

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$('#wrapper img').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var offset = $this.offset();
    $('<span>1</span>').addClass('marker').css({
        left: e.pageX-offset.left,
        top: e.pageY-offset.top
    }).appendTo($wrapper);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question: http://jsbin.com/ojahel/5/edit
Why does it get the right position only on the 2nd click?

Comment: @Cornwell because marker don't exists on first click, so the width and height is null.